# PHP_SELF displays errors on first run

Tags: php, html, forms

I have just started learning PHP and I am facing this issue when using $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] to redirect to the same page after user clicks Submit in the form. The problem are the $_POST[] variables I have used in my PHP script in the page, which I need to access AFTER user clicks Submit and the page reloads. But on the first run, when the the user hasn't clicked Submit, the $_POST variables are empty and I am getting errors displayed on the page itself. Of course, there are no errors after the user click Submit and page reloads. I don't want to redirect to another page after Submit. How do I circumvent these errors on the first run?

Is there a better approach for what I am trying to do?

The code for my page is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3> Welcome!</h3>
</br></br>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" >
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> </br></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"> </br></br>
Age: <input type="number" name="sage"> </br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></br></br>
</form>

<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user1";
    $password = "abcd123";
    $dbname = "myDbFromPhp";

    $fname = $_POST["fname"];  /*Lines responsible for the errors, I think*/
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $sage = $_POST["sage"];


    if($fname != "" and $lname != "")   /*Checking for empty vars*/
    {


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
    }

    echo "<h4>Connected successfully</h4>";


    $sql = "INSERT INTO Students
            (fname, lname, sage)
            VALUES
            ('".$fname."','".$lname."',".(string)$sage.");" ;
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "<h4>Value entered successfully</h4>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "</br>Error creating record</br>".$conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();


    }

?>
</body>

</html>
```

The page simply takes some input from the user (Student: first name, last name, age), and when user clicks Submit,  reloads and saves them to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time of page load post value not exists so use `isset` to check that like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></br></br>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     //all of your db insertion related codes all here 
      $fname = $_POST["fname"];  /*Lines responsible for the errors, I think*/
      $lname = $_POST["lname"];
      $sage = $_POST["sage"];
      ......................
      ......................


     header('Location:samepage.php');

    // redirect the page to avoid the duplicate insertion by pressing F5 or reload .
}
```

> your code looks sql injection attack . try to use prepared statement or PDO

Answer (score 0):

In your first loading, that variable does not have values, therefore php genarate a error, therefore you can use `isset()` to check whether data assigned or not

```
if(isset($_POST["fname"])){
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];  
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $sage = $_POST["sage"];
}
```

you can do all functionalities inside the  `if(isset($_POST["fname"])){     }`